# Algolia search replace character

Tags: algolia

I use Algolia on my webpage. I have a product named 56x16 . When users search for `56*16` Algolia doesn't show results. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Algolia thinks that `56x16` is one word, but `65*16` are the two words. So, it is can't be matched. You can try to store this value as `56 x 16` to see results. Or you can store this value as different properties, something like `{ width:56, height:16 }`

Also, you can read about `typeTolerance` property to load records with typos. You can read more about [typoTolerance here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/typoTolerance/)